# Magento 2 - How can I apply free shipping to specific products in the shopping cart?

Tags: magento2.3.2, free-shipping

In Magento 2.3.2, how can I apply free shipping to only certain products in my cart? I have a Cart Price rule that correctly removes shipping costs for specific SKUs (using a Condition) if those are the only SKUs in the cart. If the cart contains a mix of free-shipping and non-free-shipping SKUs, I need shipping charges to be applied to the non-free-shipping products. That isn't happening - instead free shipping applies to the entire cart.

Thanks in advance!